# Objects representing certain types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I would like to make assertions similar to the following:

```
aMethod.ReturnType == double
aString.GetType() == string
```

The above example clearly doesn't compile because `double` and `string` are not objects of type `Type`, they're not even legal C# expressions.

How do I express a `Type` of a certain C# type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use typeof to get and compare types.

```
aMethod.ReturnType == typeof(double)

aString.GetType() == typeof(string)
```

Answer (score 2):

use [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator

> Checks if an object is compatible with a given type.

<strike>bool result1 = aMethod.ReturnType is double;</strike>

```
bool result2 = aString is string;
```

Consider the following examples:

```
bool result1 = "test" is string;//returns true;
bool result2 = 2 is double; //returns false
bool result3 = 2d is double; // returns true;
```

EDIT: I missed that `aMethod.ReturnType` is a type not a value, so you are better of checking it using `typeof`

```
bool result1 = typeof(aMethod.ReturnType) == double;
```

Consider the following example.

```
object d = 10d;
bool result4 = d.GetType() == typeof(double);// returns true
```

Comment: `aMethod.ReturnType is double` this will return false and give you a compile time warning as `ReturnType` is of type `Type` and thus can't possibly be a `double`.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet, thanks for pointing that out, I missed that `ReturnType` is a type not a value

Answer (score 0):

As other people said, use `typeof(YourType)`, or the `is` operator (be carefull, `is` isn't a strict operator (think about inheritance) : for example, `MyClass is object` is true !)..

I don't know why you need `aMethod.ReturnType`, but it seems that you need [generic parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Give it a try !